# Basic properties of Cyclic extensions in Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am reading Abstract Algebra from Thomas Hungerford and got struck on this result whose proof is left to reader.

[image]

> Why did in ii nd part there is [F:K] in $N_{K}^F $ and $T_{K}^F  $ instead of $[F:K]_i$ ?

Comment: What does $[F:K]_i$ mean? Anyway, with any other integer in place of $[F:K]$ the formula would be wrong. After all, the claim in part $(ii)$ is about the determinant and trace of the scalar matrix $u I_{[F:K]}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I think another recent question established that the subscripts $i$ and $s$  indicate the inseparable and separable degrees.

Comment: @ancientmathematician That stands to reason (and would have been my guess). Anyway, it also means that the OP can view my comment as a hint :-)